# Using magrittr with the (*)apply functions - differing output

Tags: r

I read in a file into a data.frame with one column of characters and am applying some functions element-wise using `sapply`. I am interested in using the **pipes** from the `magrittr` package and am wondering what is the proper and best way to do this. I have tried a few variants out, and although it works (I  believe!), the output from the two methods does differ.

I am leaving out the placeholder for the `sapply` itself, as the `%>%` [pipes into the first parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620893/weird-error-with-lapply-and-dplyr-magrittr) of the next function.

**Original Code**

```
## Load in a CSV file as a dataframe
   y <- read.csv(file = file_name, header = TRUE, sep = "\n", quote = "", row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
## Perform so operations
y$transformed1 <- sapply(y, FUN = function(x) gsub("&amp;", "&", x))
y$transformed2 <- sapply(y$transformed1, FUN = function(x) gsub(pattern = "http\\S+\\s*", replacement = "", x)) 
y$transformed3 <- sapply(y$transformed2, FUN = function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]&\']", "", x)) 
y$transformed4 <- sapply(y$transformed3, FUN = function(x) stripWhitespace(x)) 
y$transformed5 <- sapply(y$transformed4, FUN = function(x) gsub("^ ", "", x))
y$transformed6 <- sapply(y$transformed5, FUN = function(x) gsub(" $", "", x))
```

This works splendidly for me, returning a clean result for my needs in `y$transformed6`.

**Using `magrittr`**

The following code runs nicely and on visual inspection, the result looks identical, as show in the comparison of the `head` function further below.

```
in_file <- y   ## from above

out_file <-  sapply(in_file, function(x) gsub("&amp;", "&", x)) %>%
                    gsub("http\\S+\\s*", "", .) %>%
                    gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]&\']", "", .) %>%
                    stripWhitespace() %>%
                    gsub("^ ", "", .) %>%
                    gsub(" $", "", .)
```

Here you can see the return from the `str()` and `head()` functions for each of the outputs. Using the `identical` function on them unsurprisingly returns `FALSE`.

```
## First method

> str(y$transformed6)                                
 chr [1:14158] "ExchangeNews Direct S&P Dow Jones Ind

> head(y$transformed6)                               
[1] "ExchangeNews Direct S&P Dow Jones Indices Announ
[2] "Svelte Medical Systems Raises M for HeartSurgery
[3] "Dow Jones industrial average tumbles below on bu
[4] "Dow approaches record high as Fed meeting begins
[5] "Money How the Dow Jones industrial average did T
[6] "Just another day at dowjones brewing up exciting

-----------------------------------------------------

## Using magittr

> str(out_file)                                      
 chr [1:14158, 1] "ExchangeNews Direct S&P Dow Jones 
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2                     
  ..$ : NULL                                         
  ..$ : chr "text"                                   

> head(out_file)                                     
     text                                            
[1,] "ExchangeNews Direct S&P Dow Jones Indices Annou
[2,] "Svelte Medical Systems Raises M for HeartSurger
[3,] "Dow Jones industrial average tumbles below on b
[4,] "Dow approaches record high as Fed meeting begin
[5,] "Money How the Dow Jones industrial average did 
[6,] "Just another day at dowjones brewing up excitin
```

Where is the difference coming from exactly? Have I done something wrong or is it just an artefact of using `magittr`?

Comment: It seems like you might be served best by looking at dplyr and dplyr::mutate

Comment: You only are transforming one column here? Why are you using `sapply` at all? `gsub` is a well-vectorized function in the way you are using it at least. In the piped version, you are only `sapply`-ing the first step and not the others like you did in the first scenario.

Comment: I did think that, but if I left the `sapply` out then I was gettgin back a vector, not a data frame - I need a data frame back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your pipes inside the `sapply`, not after

```
out_file <-  sapply(in_file, function(x) {gsub("&amp;", "&", x) %>%
    gsub("http\\S+\\s*", "", .) %>%
    gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]&\']", "", .) %>%
    stripWhitespace() %>%
    gsub("^ ", "", .) %>%
    gsub(" $", "", .)
})
```